# External hyperlink to Visual studio lightswitch screen

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a Visual studio lightswitch web application with a few screens. I want to create hyperlinks which will open a specific screen when the user clicks on it. Let say one example is to send a link in email which points to the add screen.

One bonus would be to even select an entity on the screen with a link. Like: 
http:\app.com\companies\id=4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it is not supported out of box but with a few lines of codes it can be implemented.
Url parameters are stored in `System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.QueryString` however the object cannot be access directly you need to use `Microsoft.LightSwitch.Threading.Dispatchers.Main.BeginInvoke`

After you have the parameters you just need to fire up the necessary screen and change the SelectedItem. A tiny addition that `SelectionChanged()` method also needs to be called to reflect the change in the UX.